# Selenium IDE requires 2 identical commands for button press

Tags: selenium, double, selenium-ide, double-click

Here is an exerpt from my Selenium script

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=a.btn.btn-style-c[href=&quot;/shortlist/Remove/${codeparc}&quot;]</td>
    <td>isSelected</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${isSelected}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${isSelected}==true</td>
    <td>skipToRemoveFromShortlist</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.btn.btn-style-c[href=&quot;/shortlist/Add/${codeparc}&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.btn.btn-style-c[href=&quot;/shortlist/Add/${codeparc}&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoLabel</td>
    <td>endOfShortlisting</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>skipToRemoveFromShortlist</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.btn.btn-style-c[href=&quot;/shortlist/Remove/${codeparc}&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.btn.btn-style-c[href=&quot;/shortlist/Remove/${codeparc}&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>endOfShortlisting</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=cboxClose</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Commands 4 and 5 are duplicates

Commands 8 and 9 are duplicates

In step through mode if I execute the command twice it works fine.

Test page for you to look at - www.eurocamp.co.uk/pa012

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: Why?? - Why should I need two commands to click a button.... The button should just click with one command surely.

Comment: It maybe because Add button is not visible on current page display, so first click will move control to element and second one will actually click it.